# Allow external website users to download documents stored in Office 365 / SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I have been asked to develop a website that is integrated with CRM2013 and SharePoint 2013 Online.

This website is for external users without an Office 365 login to view data stored in CRM and SharePoint.

Part of the website displays documents with a URL link pointing into SharePoint Online Document Storage.

When the user clicks to access the document, the Office 365 login prompt is displayed as the user does not have an account.

Is the only way to do this by offering an 'anonymous guest link'?

Is there any way to allow external website users access access and download documents stored in Office 365 / SharePoint online without having to give them an Office 365 login?

Would it be possible to programmatically login to Office 365 and stream the document back to the user via HTTP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?